# accept unevaluated logical expression as argument, defer execute

Tags: python

target code:

```
    test_box = TestBox(Checkers.begin_with("op") and Checkers.end_with("or"))
    test_box.run("operator")  # True
    test_box.run("option")  # False
```

What I think(may be in the wrong way): `TestBox` may be a class or a method, and `begin_with` and `end_with` are classmethod of class `Checkers`, but how to make `Checkers.begin_with("op") and Checkers.end_with("or")` evaluated until `test_box.run()` was called?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: @TedBrownlow there is a lot of record exacted from logs every day, I try to provide a python tool to accept user‘s checkers  joined by logic operators and return the records satisfied. for examle   `begin_with("user_mark") and end_with("porn") and begin_with("model_result") and end_with("not_sure")`   user can write a template file list the checkers they concerned， and I parser the template  print the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution which use lambda, post here:

```
class TestBox:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self._func = func

    def run(self, string):
        Checkers.string = string
        return self._func()


class Checkers:
    string = None

    @classmethod
    def begin_with(cls, val):
        return cls.string.startswith(val)

    @classmethod
    def end_with(cls, val):
        return cls.string.endswith(val)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_box = TestBox(lambda: Checkers.begin_with("op") or Checkers.end_with("or"))
    print(test_box.run("operator"))  # True
    print(test_box.run("xxtion"))  # False
    print(test_box.run("xxtionor"))  # True
```